# Hiding and showing two tooltips on hovering and clicking using angular js and bootstrap tooltip

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I've two tooltips for the same anchor and I need to show one on hover and other one on click using angular js. I tried with ng-mouseover & ng-mouseleave but the tooltip is not hidding on leaving the focus.Also On clicking and having the mouse on the anchor, the hover tooltip should be hidden.Is there any solution to fix?

html code:

```
<a href="#" class="infoTip" tabindex="0" ng-mouseover="vm.tooltipHover($event)"
                    ng-mouseleave="vm.toolTipHide($event)"
                     alt="my tooltip" ng-click="vm.handleInfo($event)" ng-focus="vm.closeMenus()">
                     <span data-toggle="tooltipHover" class="tooltipHover" data-trigger="manual" data-placement="top" title="" data-html="true" data-content="Info for this section"></span>
                        <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>

                        <span data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="manual" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-html="true" data-content="hello"></span>
                    </a>



vm.handleInfo = function(event){
            $('.infoIconTip').toggle();
            $(event.currentTarget).parent().find('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('toggle');

        };
        vm.tooltipHover = function(event){  
            $(event.currentTarget).parent().find('[data-toggle="tooltipHover"]').popover('toggle');
        };

        vm.toolTipHide = function(event){
            $(event.currentTarget).parent().find('[data-toggle="tooltipHover"]').hide();
        };
```

Because the tooltip have different styles I have two seperate classes.